# Where is the "mark occurrences" ("highlight selection") option/plugin?

Tags: kdevelop

When putting text cursor on a word I'd like other occurrences of this word to be highlighted.

I saw that it worked like that before. But how to enable it in the current version?

There is a highlight occurrences when selecting the whole word, but that's not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The on-hover occurrence highlighting is a product of the semantic analysis backend.

Note that it doesn't highlight uses of a *word*, it highlights uses of a *variable* - i.e. the same name might exist in different scopes and their uses will be highlighted separately, uses in comments won't be marked, etc.

You should also notice that there's a tooltip when hovering over variables with type and other information, and that variable names are differently-coloured (unless you've set 'Local colourisation intensity' to zero in `Configure Kdevelop` -> `Language Support`).

If this isn't the case it probably means the semantic analysis backend isn't working -- either because the project settings aren't configured properly, or you lack the right plugin for the language you're using, or some dependency is missing.